# Sitecore Connect for Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Sales 2.0.1 - Getting Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference instead of ID on reference entities

Tags: data-exchange-framework, dynamics-crm-module

We are trying to get entity ID when synchronizing `Dynamics 365` entities into `Sitecore 9.0.1` using `Sitecore Connect for Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Sales 2.0.1` module.
What is the best solution? We are getting currently Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference as value instead of ID. Can we get also other properties from the referenced entity like `emailaddress` and so on. We are trying to sync `Cases` and corresponding `Customer` field (and its id or email address).

In Dynamics 365:
[image]

In Sitecore:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get customer id you have to change your accessor template to

[image]

It should be something like this

[image]

And if the value Guid type you can use transformer Guid to String.

Comment: I tried using the solution above, but I get an error message on batch pipeline saying the the 'Sample' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name 'Sample Attr' the 'Sample Attr' is a from the related entity.

Comment: Probably the attribute name is sampleatt or something similar. You need to go to Entity definition and in Field definition take Name field not Display Name -> https://ramontebar.net/2017/09/13/dynamics-365-attribute-name-lengths/

Comment: <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
    <link-entity name="sample_Related" from="sam_account" to="accountid" link-type="inner" alias="aa">
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="SampleAttr" operator="not-null" />
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>

here is my sample XML and im tryong to get it from a link-entity attribute name. SampleAttr